# Backslash escape for single quote in sed produces an error

Tags: bash, escape-characters

The intention is to insert right after the `HEAD` Google tag code in a legacy HTML website.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -iname "*.php" -or -iname "*.htm" -or -iname "*.html" | while read i; do
    echo "Processing: $i"
    sed -i 's*<HEAD>*&\
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->\
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1234567-2"></script>\
<script>\
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}\
  gtag('js', new Date());\
\
  gtag('config', 'UA-1234567-2');\
</script>*' "$i"

done
```

The above puts the Google tag code where it should, but without the single quotes:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1234567-2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag(js, new Date());

  gtag(config, UA-1234567-2);
```

The single quotes are missing after it is processed:

```
# diff actual_google_tag_code processed
6c6
<   gtag('js', new Date());
---
>   gtag(js, new Date());
8,9c8
<   gtag('config', 'UA-1234567-2');
< </script>
---
>   gtag(config, UA-1234567-2);
```

If I replace the `'` with a `\'`, I get an error message:

```
line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 13: `  gtag(\'js\', new Date());\'
```

Since I'm using `\` to continue each line, I wasn't sure the backslash to escape the single quote would work, but I thought I would give it a try.

How can I preserve those single quotes in the Google Tag code?

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ shows your original code is horribly broken (I don't know the answer though). Lots of warnings "This backslash+linefeed is literal. Break outside single quotes if you just want to break the line." because everything is inside a single quoted string starting on the `sed` line.

Comment: I don't know if this is portable, but in GNUsed could be with hexadecimal escape `sed 's/f/\x27/' <<<foo` or decimal escape `sed 's/f/\d039/' <<<foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man 1 bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Solution: place single quote(s) inside double quotes:

```
  gtag('"'js'"', new Date());\
#      ^        - single quote was opened earlier, this character closes it
#       ^^^^^^  - these are double quotes with content, single quotes are part of the content
#             ^ - this single quote will be closed later
# Do not paste these comments into your script.
```

Repeat this trick wherever you need, it will be like:

```
  gtag('"'config', 'UA-1234567-2'"');\
```

(remember this line continues the previous, where a single quote is already opened; at the end it leaves it open to be closed in the next line).

In general it's possible to place only `'` in double quotes, leaving everything else in single quotes, e.g.:

```
echo '$A'"'"'$B'"'"'$C'
#     ^^     ^^     ^^ - in single quotes, so no variable expansion here
#         ^      ^     - in double quotes, so ' is possible
```

The result is `$A'$B'$C`.

Comment: I tried putting double-quotes around the single quotes, but that resulted in there being a double quote instead of a single one. Am I missing something?

Comment: gtag('"'js'"', new Date());\ works and so does gtag('"'config', 'UA-1234567-2'"');\ I'm just having a hard time understand why this works. :-)

Comment: @Edward_178118 Just replace your two lines with my respective ones. The trick is not just to double quote these single quotes; you need to close an old single quote just before and reopen just after. Invalid `'foo'bar'` becomes valid `'foo'"'"'bar'`.

Comment: You said, "single quote was opened earlier". Where is it open earlier? The first single quote is in gtag(' ?

Comment: The first single quote is the 's ?

Comment: @Edward_178118 In the modified version, here: `sed -i 's*<HEAD>*&\ ` – the line continues.